# skyway android sdk client and peerjs as server

Tags: android, webrtc, peerjs

Hi I'm trying to build a video chat app for android and I'm using the skayway sdk it works fine on their cloud but I want to run it on a peerjs server as they mentioned in their doc it is possible
I used this sample as android client [skyway android sample](https://github.com/nttcom/SkyWay-Android-Sample) and I used this as server [server peerJS](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server)

the server works fine

```
Started PeerServer on ::, port: 9000, path: / (v. 0.2.8)
```

I tried changing the Peer option on the android client but no trace for conection on the server side  any help please

```
PeerOption options = new PeerOption();

    options.host="my ip adress";
            options.port=9000;
            options.path="/";
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Am stuck with same problem

Comment: sorry no solution found for me instead I used webrtc android apprtc was useful for me